# My sprite is hovering slightly above my tilemap in Unity 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap, collider

I have a simple object with a `Rigidbody 2D` and a `Box Collider 2d`, that's supposed to fall and land on a tilemap with a static `Rigidbody 2D` and a `Composite Collider 2D`. However, it slightly hovers above, as seen in the below picture. I've tried fiddling with edge radius and other settings, however, it doesn't seem to work. The gap can be seen in both the scene view and the play mode, so it's not a rendering problem. Any ideas?

[image: zoomed-up image]

[image: the whole scene]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to fix this:

1- Go to Project Setting and then Physics 2D and change the value of Default Contact Offset to something smaller

2- make the collider slightly smaller than the sprite

3- use an Edge Collider instead of a Box Collider

Personally, I would go with the second option as the other two have their own issues:

- Edge collider doesn't call functions like `OnCollisionEnter2D` and that may become a problem for you
- changing the value of Default Contact Offset may result in a "glitchy" gameplay (like when the player jumps and then collides with the ground)

Comment: this was perfect! these solution options are exactly what I was looking for. For now I'm going with a combination of the first 2 and its working great!

Comment: @MaxBailey you're welcome! just remember about the issues I've mentioned